# Ninject Moqing Kernel (what does reset do?)

Tags: ninject, moq

I have an interface that I'm using with a couple different concrete classes.  What I wish is that there was something like this...

```
_kernel.GetMock<ISerializeToFile>().Named("MyRegisteredName")
    .Setup(x => x.Read<ObservableCollection<PointCtTestDataInput>>(
        It.IsAny<string>()));
```

The project I'm working on uses the service locator pattern - anti-pattern which I'm getting less fond of all the time...

Originally I tried..

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    _kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
}

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    _kernel.Reset();
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(
        () => new NinjectServiceLocator(_kernel));
    _kernel.Bind<ISerializeToFile>().ToMock()
        .InSingletonScope().Named("ObjectToFile");
    _kernel.GetMock<ISerializeToFile>()
        .Setup(x => x.Read<ObservableCollection<PointCtTestDataInput>>(
            It.IsAny<string>()));
    _kernel.GetMock<ISerializeToFile>()
        .Setup(x => x.Save<ObservableCollection<PointCtTestDataInput>>(
            It.IsAny<ObservableCollection<PointCtTestDataInput>>(), 
            It.IsAny<string>()));
}
```

I got the standard Ninject error stating that more than one matching binding is available. So, I moved `_kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();`  into the TestInitialize, and then that error went away...  Perhaps I'm incorrectly guess at what _kernel.Reset() does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset removes any instance from the cache. It does not delete existing bindings. So the second test will have the `ISerializeToFile` twice.